# How to close a readable stream (before end)?

Tags: node.js, stream, fs

How to close a [readable stream](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) in Node.js?

```
var input = fs.createReadStream('lines.txt');

input.on('data', function(data) {
   // after closing the stream, this will not
   // be called again

   if (gotFirstLine) {
      // close this stream and continue the
      // instructions from this if
      console.log("Closed.");
   }
});
```

This would be better than:

```
input.on('data', function(data) {
   if (isEnded) { return; }

   if (gotFirstLine) {
      isEnded = true;
      console.log("Closed.");
   }
});
```

But this would not stop the reading process...

Comment: Warning: This question is only in the context of the `fs` module. `close` does not exist in `Stream.Readable`.

Comment: Good news. Node version 8 provides [`stream.destroy()`](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v8.0.0/#stream-api-improvements)

Comment: can't you call `readable.push(null) && readable.destroy();`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Invoke `input.close()`. It's not in the docs, but

https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/cfcb1de130867197cbc9c6012b7e84e08e53d032/lib/fs.js#L1597-L1620

clearly does the job :) It actually does something similar to your `isEnded`.

**EDIT 2015-Apr-19** Based on comments below, and to clarify and update:

- This suggestion is a hack, and is not documented.
- Though for looking at the current `lib/fs.js` it still works >1.5yrs later.
- I agree with the comment below about calling `destroy()` being preferable.
- As correctly stated below this works for `fs` `ReadStreams`'s, not on a generic `Readable`

As for a generic solution: it doesn't appear as if there is one, at least from my understanding of the documentation and from a quick look at `_stream_readable.js`.

My proposal would be put your readable stream in *paused* mode, at least preventing further processing in your upstream data source. Don't forget to `unpipe()` and remove all `data` event listeners so that `pause()` actually pauses, as mentioned in [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable)

Comment: Actually I would prefer calling `destroy` instead. At least that's what is called if you set autoClose to true. By looking at the source code (today) the differences are minimal (`destroy` calls `close`) but that could change in the future

Comment: Don't remember by now, but looks like it :)

Comment: There is no `close()` on object Readable, is there a never solution? My data exchange is always incomplete...

Comment: Updated to clarify, address comments, and provide a (poor man's) suggestion for the generic case. Though it does make some sense to not force a generic `readable` to implement `close()`, and provide a class-specific way of doing this (as is the case in `fs`, and presumably other classes implementing `Readable`)

Comment: Won't pausing cause the upstream (sender) to block due to backpressure, or otherwise cause buffers to grow until they exceed their limits? Ideally we would tell the sender that it is no longer wanted...

Answer (score 120):

**Edit:** Good news! Starting with Node.js 8.0.0 `readable.destroy` is officially available: https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_destroy_error

### ReadStream.destroy

You can call the [ReadStream.destroy](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.12.2-release/lib/fs.js#L1685) function at any time.

```
var fs = require("fs");

var readStream = fs.createReadStream("lines.txt");
readStream
    .on("data", function (chunk) {
        console.log(chunk);
        readStream.destroy();
    })
    .on("end", function () {
        // This may not been called since we are destroying the stream
        // the first time "data" event is received
        console.log("All the data in the file has been read");
    })
    .on("close", function (err) {
        console.log("Stream has been destroyed and file has been closed");
    });
```

The public function `ReadStream.destroy` is not documented (Node.js v0.12.2) but you can have a look at the [source code on GitHub](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.12.2-release/lib/fs.js#L1685) ([Oct 5, 2012 commit](https://github.com/joyent/node/commit/44b308b1f7beaa3398d869f1626f01ae6526bc0b)).

The `destroy` function internally mark the `ReadStream` instance as destroyed and calls the `close` function to release the file.

You can listen to the [close event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_close) to know exactly when the file is closed. The [end event](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_event_end) will not fire unless the data is completely consumed.

---

Note that the `destroy` (and the `close`) functions are specific to [fs.ReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_readstream). There are not part of the generic [stream.readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_readable) "interface".

Comment: At least in the latest version of Node (haven't checked the others), the file descriptor is [closed automatically](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options).

That said, I haven't done any kind of thorough test to ensure that the stream eventually fires `error` if it is never read.  

Aside from that, the only other leak I'd worry about is event handlers-- once again, I'm not 100% sure on this, but we might be ok b/c the 2010 the gospel of Isaacs does say that handlers are pruned when emitters are gc'd: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/nodejs/pXbJVo0NtaY/BxUmF_jp9LkJ

Comment: If data is too small, the `on('data')`  will only trigger once, so there will not any `.close()`, just remind someone else.

Comment: you can actually use `this.destroy()` unless you're using an arrow function. Lexical `this` I hate you :D

Comment: I'm using `pipe()` and I had to move `on("close")` to be before `.pipe()` an `on("data")`, otherwise I wasn't able to catch "close" event

Comment: @MaximMazurok you are a life saver brother, this had me spinning for hours, Thanks!

Answer (score 27):

Today, in Node 10

`readableStream.destroy()`

is the official way to close a readable stream

see https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_destroy_error

Answer (score 14):

You can't. There is no documented way to close/shutdown/abort/destroy a generic [Readable](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html) stream as of Node 5.3.0. This is a limitation of the Node stream architecture.

As other answers here have explained, there are undocumented hacks for specific implementations of Readable provided by Node, such as [fs.ReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html). These are not generic solutions for any Readable though.

If someone can prove me wrong here, please do. I would like to be able to do what I'm saying is impossible, and would be delighted to be corrected.

**EDIT**: Here was my workaround: [implement `.destroy()` for my pipeline though a complex series of `unpipe()` calls.](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl/commit/594cd7ea712ec21f8f6eb80d9ac52b9ad7d1b76b) And after all that complexity, it [doesn't work properly in all cases](https://github.com/thejoshwolfe/yauzl/issues/27).

**EDIT**: Node v8.0.0 added a [`destroy()` api for Readable streams](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v8.x/api/stream.html#stream_readable_destroy_err_callback).

Comment: There’s now [`stream.pipeline`](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_stream_pipeline_streams_callback), which claims to handle “forwarding errors and properly cleaning up and provide a callback when the pipeline is complete.” Does that help?

Answer (score 14):

At version `4.*.*` pushing a null value into the stream will trigger a `EOF` signal.

From the [nodejs docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_push_chunk_encoding)

> If a value other than null is passed, The push() method adds a chunk of data into the queue for subsequent stream processors to consume. If null is passed, it signals the end of the stream (EOF), after which no more data can be written.

This worked for me after trying numerous other options on this page.

Comment: Works for me. However, I needed to avoid calling the done() callback after pushing null to get the expected behavior - namely that the entire stream halts.

Answer (score 7):

This [destroy](https://www.npmjs.com/package/destroy) module is meant to ensure a stream gets destroyed, handling different APIs and Node.js bugs. Right now is one of the best choice.

**NB.** From Node 10 you can use the `.destroy` method without further dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

You can clear and close the stream with `yourstream.resume()`, which will dump everything on the stream and eventually close it.

From the [official docs](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_resume):

> readable.resume():
>
> Return: this
>
> This method will cause the readable stream to resume emitting 'data' events.
>
> This method will switch the stream into flowing mode. If you do not want to consume the data from a stream, but you do want to get to its 'end' event, you can call stream.resume() to open the flow of data.

```
var readable = getReadableStreamSomehow();
readable.resume();
readable.on('end', () => {
  console.log('got to the end, but did not read anything');
});
```

Comment: This can be called "draining" the stream. In our case, of course we had a `'data'` event listener, but we made it check a boolean `if (!ignoring) { ... }` so it won't process data when we are draining the stream. `ignoring = true; readable.resume();`

Comment: Of course this assumes the stream will `'end'` at some point. Not all streams will do that! (E.g. a stream that sends the date every second, forever.)

Answer (score 3):

It's an old question but I too was looking for the answer and found the best one for my implementation. Both `end` and `close` events get emitted so I think this is the cleanest solution.

This will do the trick in node 4.4.* (stable version at the time of writing):

```
var input = fs.createReadStream('lines.txt');

input.on('data', function(data) {
   if (gotFirstLine) {
      this.end(); // Simple isn't it?
      console.log("Closed.");
   }
});
```

For a very detailed explanation see:
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2692-you-have-to-explicitly-end-streams-after-pipes-break-in-node-js.htm

Answer (score 2):

This code here will do the trick nicely:

```
function closeReadStream(stream) {
    if (!stream) return;
    if (stream.close) stream.close();
    else if (stream.destroy) stream.destroy();
}
```

writeStream.end() is the go-to way to close a writeStream...

Comment: Why do you mention .end() is the go-to way, but then your code uses close and destroy and doesn't even use end?

Comment: i am closing a readStream in the example... a writeStream -- use `.end`

Answer (score 0):

for stop callback execution after some call,
you have to use process.kill with particular processID

```js
const csv = require('csv-parser');
const fs = require('fs');

const filepath = "./demo.csv"
let readStream = fs.createReadStream(filepath, {
    autoClose: true,
});
let MAX_LINE = 0;


readStream.on('error', (e) => {
        console.log(e);
        console.log("error");
    })

    .pipe(csv())
    .on('data', (row) => {

        if (MAX_LINE == 2) {
            process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGTERM')
        }
        // console.log("not 2");
        MAX_LINE++
        console.log(row);
    })

    .on('end', () => {
        // handle end of CSV
        console.log("read done");
    }).on("close", function () {
        console.log("closed");
    })
```