# Close readable stream to FIFO in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, stream, fifo

I am creating a readable stream to a linux fifo in nodejs like this:

```
var stream = FS.createReadStream('fifo');
```

This all works well and I can receive the data from the fifo just fine.
My problem is that I want to have a method to **shut my software down gently** and therefore I need to close this stream somehow.

Calling

```
process.exit();
```

does have no effect as the stream is blocking.

I also tried to destroy the stream manually by calling the undocumented methods `stream.close()` as well as `stream.destroy()` as described [in the answers of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277094/how-to-close-a-readable-stream-before-end).

I know that I could kill my own process using `process.kill(process.pid, 'SIGKILL')` but this feels like a really bad hack and could have bad impacts on the filesystem or database.

Isn't there a better way to achieve this?

You can try this **minimal example** to reproduce my problem:

```
var FS = require('fs');
console.log("Creating readable stream on fifo ...");
var stream = FS.createReadStream('fifo');
stream.once('close', function() {
    console.log("The close event was emitted.");
});
stream.close();
stream.destroy();
process.exit();
```

After creating a fifo called 'fifo' using `mkfifo fifo`.

How could I modify the above code to shutdown the software correctly?

Comment: Creating the stream like this: ```stream = FS.createReadStream('fifo', {flags : 'r+'});``` and then closing it like this
```var c = FS.createWriteStream('fifo'); c.write('\0'); c.close(); stream.pause(); stream.close(); ```
works, but it feels more like a dirty hack.

Comment: there is an explanation in the node docs: https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v11.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options

Answer (score 1):

Explicitly writing to the named pipe will unblock the read operation, for example:

```
require('child_process').execSync('echo "" > fifo');
process.exit();
```