# Splitting a text file based on number of lines in node.js

Tags: node.js

Hitting the limit of my understanding here. I have a large text file that I need to split into chunks 200 lines each (use mime.types to practice). I'm using `readline` but it seems to ignore my `pause / resume` statements. What do I miss:

```
// Splits a given file into smaller subfiles by line number
var infileName = 'mime.types';
var fileCount = 1;
var count = 0;
var fs = require('fs');
var outfileName = infileName + '.' + fileCount;
var inStream = fs.createReadStream(infileName);
var outStream = fs.createWriteStream(outfileName);
var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
  input: inStream
});

lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
  count++;
  lineReader.pause();
  outStream.write(line + '\n');
  if (count >= 200) {
    fileCount++;
    console.log('file ', outfileName, count);
    outStream.close();
    outfileName = infileName + '.' + fileCount;
    outStream = fs.createWriteStream(outfileName);
    count = 0;
  }
  lineReader.resume();
});

lineReader.on('close', function() {
  if (count > 0) {
    console.log('Final close:', outfileName, count);
  }
  inStream.close();
  outStream.close();
  console.log('Done');
});
```

I also tried to put the change of stream into the callback of the write operation:

```
lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
  count++;
  lineReader.pause();
  outStream.write(line + '\n', function() {
    if (count >= 200) {
      fileCount++;
      console.log('file ', outfileName, count);
      outStream.close();
      outfileName = infileName + '.' + fileCount;
      outStream = fs.createWriteStream(outfileName);
      count = 0;
    }
    lineReader.resume();
  });
});
```

The result is the same in both cases:
`node split
file  mime.types.1 1588
Done`

Ideally I want a solution that doesn't rely on extra npm

Comment: Which readline are you using ? core or https://www.npmjs.com/package/readline ?

Comment: Core only. Wonder if that's solvable using core

Comment: How many times does the line event is dispatched ? Can you set a breakpoint ?

Comment: 1588 times :-). The irony... I commented out the .write event and it then would created the expected number of files - empty of course. You can try. You will for sure have the file mime.types somewhere on disk (I just used it to test since it is nice, long and text only)

Comment: If I remove the pause() and resume(), it works as expected... `file  mime.types.1 200
file  mime.types.2 200
file  mime.types.3 200
file  mime.types.4 200
file  mime.types.5 200
file  mime.types.6 200
file  mime.types.7 200
Final close: mime.types.8 188`

Comment: But the files contain a single line... hmm

Comment: You can use this core module, https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html

Comment: @BlackMamba - that's what I'm using. Seems not to react to pause() / resume()

Comment: @Ludo: yep - that's the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I got rid of the pause / resume. They seem like they are not supported by the readline stream. All I did is to provide a new writable stream every 200 line.

```js
// Splits a given file into smaller subfiles by line number
var infileName = 'mime.types';
var fileCount = 1;
var count = 0;
var fs = require('fs');
var outStream;
var outfileName = infileName + '.' + fileCount;
newWriteStream();
var inStream = fs.createReadStream(infileName);

var lineReader = require('readline').createInterface({
    input: inStream
});

function newWriteStream(){
    outfileName = infileName + '.' + fileCount;
    outStream = fs.createWriteStream(outfileName);
    count = 0;
}

lineReader.on('line', function(line) {
    count++;
    outStream.write(line + '\n');
    if (count >= 200) {
        fileCount++;
        console.log('file ', outfileName, count);
        outStream.end();
        newWriteStream();
    }
});

lineReader.on('close', function() {
    if (count > 0) {
        console.log('Final close:', outfileName, count);
    }
    inStream.close();
    outStream.end();
    console.log('Done');
});
```

Comment: The difference in the code seems to be outStream.end() vs. outStream.close() - tricky

Comment: close is a readline specific method https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html#readline_rl_close

Comment: No I'm wrong http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277094/how-to-close-a-readable-stream-before-end

Comment: I think you should call lineReader.close() instead