# Files/directories not deleting until node.js restarts

Tags: linux, node.js, redhat, fs, pm2

I have a large node.js project that deals with the linux redhat filesystem quite a bit, and is being managed by PM2. I'm using fs and rimraf for disk cleanup on a redhat AWS ephemeral drive.

When running through all of the disk cleanup operations, the files are deleted, but kept open by node.js until it's restarted. Using `df` shows that the disk is full, but `du` shows the disk as clean, which would make sense.

It's my understanding that when using `fs`, if you use `fs.open` you need to call `fs.close`, but these functions are never in use. The fs operations I'm using are:

`fs.writeFile`
`fs.readdirSync`
`fs.lstatSync`
`fs.existsSync`
`fs.mkdirSync`
`fs.chownSync`
`fs.unlink`
`fs.rmdirSync`
`fs.writeFile`
`fs.createReadStream`
`fs.createWriteStream`

Rimraf is also being used, but looking through their code, I don't think that's the problem.

I believe all of these functions manage closing themselves, according to the documentation, but if somebody knows something I didn't see that help would be appreciated.

My other fear is that `pm2` is somehow keeping files open, is that possible?

Comment: which node version are you using ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[fs.createWriteStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options) requires manual `fs.close()`. [fs.createReadStream](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createwritestream_path_options) also requires it, unless you set the `autoClose` option and then read the file all the way until end or error.

Comment: Is `fs.close()` or `fs.destroy()` the preferred method for read streams?

Comment: Interesting. Seems that there is no documented way, but the folks who have read and discussed the source [suggest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19277382/2063220) `stream.destroy()`.