# How to stop a nodejs LineInputStream?

Tags: node.js, express

I am processing a csv file and when I found a validation error and want the script to stop processing newlines.

```
router.use(upload.single('csv')).route('/agency/:agencyId/properties/import').post(function (req, res) {

  var stream = LineInputStream(fs.createReadStream(req.file.path, {flags: 'r'}));
  stream.setDelimiter("\n");

  stream.on('line', function(line) {
    var row = line.split(',');
    if (row.length!=15) {
      stream.end(); // this does not stop the processing of new lines
      return res.status(400).json({error: 'File should have 15 columns.'});
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [stream.destroy()](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_destroy_error=) inside the line handler function and then attach an error handler to the stream that returns an error response.

Refer to [How to close a readable stream (before end)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19277094/how-to-close-a-readable-stream-before-end)